# How do you get all store parameters? (ExtJS 4.1)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How I'll get all the parameters that will be send when store.load() is run? I mean, I will not run store.load() but I want to get all request parameters. How I'll do it? (This is a grid's store)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to see all the parameters?

Comment: @sha, I'll use it to create an excel file.

Answer (score 7):

Building off how the source code produces the params, here is a function that will produce the desired results, just know that if you were to updated Extjs beyond 4.1 that it may stop working by the nature of the background code changing:

```
function getParamsObject(store){
    var options = {
        groupers:   store.groupers.items,
        page:       store.currentPage,
        start:      (store.currentPage - 1) * store.pageSize,
        limit:      store.pageSize,
        addRecords: false,
        action:     'read',
        filters:    store.filters.items,
        sorters:    store.getSorters()
    };
    var operation = new Ext.data.Operation(options);

    var fakeRequest = store.getProxy().buildRequest(operation);
    var params = fakeRequest.params;

    return params;
}
```

Comment: why it is throwing error "buildRequest is not a function" ?

Comment: Prasu, you're probably on a different version.  This is an internal function which is subject to change.  Extjs 4.1 is pretty old at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have loaded your store you can find parameters as below:

```
store.proxy.extraParams
```

Comment: It shows the extra parameter `meta`. However the `sort`, `start`, `limit`, and `page` are missing.

Comment: You will find values for those properties in store object.